# How can I resolve BUILD_EXCLUSIVE error in upgrade to 3.19.7 Kernel?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I ran the following commands to upgrade from 3.19.0 to 3.19.7:

```
$ cd /tmp

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.7-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic_3.19.7-031907.201505062136_amd64.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.7-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.7-031907_3.19.7-031907.201505062136_all.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.7-vivid/linux-image-3.19.7-031907-generic_3.19.7-031907.201505062136_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.19.7-*.deb linux-image-3.19.7-*.deb
```

Everything appears to be running okay, but here is where it starts to get funky:

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.7-031907-generic (3.19.7-031907.201505062136) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.19.7-031907 (3.19.7-031907.201505062136) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic (3.19.7-031907.201505062136) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.19.7-031907-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.7-031907-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.7-031907-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

Not really understanding why it is blowing up, I examine the make.log to find:

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-updates-13.350.1 for kernel
3.19.7-031907-generic (x86_64) Thu May  7 23:59:48 EDT 2015 /usr/sbin/dkms: line 73: cd: /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.350.1/build: No such file or directory AMD kernel module generator version 2.1 doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher rm -rf *.c *.h *.o
*.ko *.a .??* *.symvers make -C /lib/modules/3.19.7-031907-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x modules make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic'   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘kasSetExecutionLevel’: /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4733:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__get_cpu_var’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     orig_level = __get_cpu_var(kasExecutionLevel);
     ^ /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4734:38: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     __get_cpu_var(kasExecutionLevel) = level;
                                      ^ cc1: some warnings being treated as errors make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-updates/13.350.1/build/2.6.x] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic' make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2 build failed with return value 2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing all files with the command below.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.19.* linux-image-3.19.* && sudo update-grub
```

I reverted back to 3.18.-something. I then ran through the exact same steps and it seems to have worked the second go around.

Not sure why that error came up, but removing the files and starting over helped.